# Concatenate and sort data in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have a few numpy arrays like so:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [14, 16, 17, 27, 38]])
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [.4, .2, .5, .1, .6]])
```

I'd like to be able to 1.Copy these arrays into a new single array and 2. Sort the data so that the result is as follows:

```
data = [[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], [14, .4, 16, .2, 17, .5, 27, .1, 38, .6]]
```

Or, in other words, I need all columns from the original array to be the same, just in an ascending order. I tried this:

```
data = np.hstack((a,b))
```

Which gave me the appended data, but I'm not sure how to sort it. I tried np.sort() but it didn't keep the columns the same. Thanks!

Comment: What you describe is not sorting.

Comment: Then what is and what isn't sorting?

Comment: You convert `[a, b, c]`, `[d, e, f]` into `[a, d, b, e, c, f]`, not `sorted([a, d, b, e, c, f])`. You perform sorting on pairs of `zip([a, b, c], [d, e, f])`.

Comment: Yes, but that was my question -- how to go from [a, d, b, e, c, f] to [a, b, c, d, e, f]. Is that not sorting my array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack those horizontally (as you already did), then get `argsort` indices for sorting first row and use those to sort all columns in the stacked array.

Thus, we need to add one more step, like so -

```
ab = np.hstack((a,b))
out = ab[:,ab[0].argsort()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [370]: a
Out[370]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [14, 16, 17, 27, 38]])

In [371]: b
Out[371]: 
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  5. ],
       [ 0.4,  0.2,  0.5,  0.1,  0.6]])

In [372]: ab = np.hstack((a,b))

In [373]: print ab[:,ab[0].argsort()]
[[  1.    1.    2.    2.    3.    3.    4.    4.    5.    5. ]
 [ 14.    0.4  16.    0.2  17.    0.5  27.    0.1  38.    0.6]]
```

Please note that to keep the order for identical elements, we need to use to use `kind='mergesort'` with `argsort` as described in the [`docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you like something short.

```
np.array(zip(*sorted(zip(*np.hstack((a,b))))))

>>> array([[  1. ,   1. ,   2. ,   2. ,   3. ,   3. ,   4. ,   4. ,   5. ,   5. ],
   [  0.4,  14. ,   0.2,  16. ,   0.5,  17. ,   0.1,  27. ,   0.6,  38. ]])
```

Version that preserve second element order:

```
np.array(zip(*sorted(zip(*np.hstack((a,b))),key=lambda x:x[0])))

>>>array([[  1. ,   1. ,   2. ,   2. ,   3. ,   3. ,   4. ,   4. ,   5. ,   5. ],
          [ 14. ,   0.4,  16. ,   0.2,  17. ,   0.5,  27. ,   0.1,  38. ,0.6]])
```